# use "promisify" from the node util module but I have an error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules

```
const { promisify } = require('util')


module.exports = (db,redisDb) =>{
    const saddAsync = promisify(redisDb.sadd).bind(redisDb)
    
    return async(request, response) =>{
   
    const result = await db.collection('polls').updateOne({
          _id: request.params.poll,
          'choices._id': request.body.choice
     },{
         $inc:{
             'choices.$.count':1
         }
     })
     await saddAsync(request.params.poll, request.body.ip)

     return response.json({
         message: 'vote has been registered.'
     })
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do NOT post pictures of code, post the actual code. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The error indicates that what you pass to `promisify` is `undefined`. Make sure that what you pass to it is actually a function that has a callback argument.

Comment: this is my code i pass actually function with calback argument